# Menu sizing issues

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, user-interface

I have a issue with my mega menu sizing. The desktop menu has a hover drop-down mega menu. The mega menus are going to be both 5 column and four column. I cant get the menu to size properly around the columns. currently its set close to what I'd like for the 5 column menu, however there is some text wrapping and id rather have the menu size itself appropriately. The four column has too much white space. I've tried a few things like switching width for max width but that doesn't solve the problem. Id really like to make the mega menu more responsive.

Codepen:https://codepen.io/iamgonge/pen/QpOgZB

desktop nav css:

```
/* Main Nav syle */

nav {
    position: relative;
}
ul.main-nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 0px;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
ul.main-nav h2 {
    font-size: .9em;
    font-weight: 300;
}
ul.main-nav > li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
}
ul.main-nav > li > a {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px 15px;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul.main-nav > li:hover {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
ul.main-nav > li:hover > a {
    color: #333;
    font-weight: 400;
}
ul.main-nav > li ul.sub-menu-lists {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 1px;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: block;
}
ul.main-nav > li ul.sub-menu-lists > li {
    padding: 0 0px;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
ul.main-nav > li ul.sub-menu-lists > li > a {
    font-size: 14px;

}
.sub-menu-head {
    margin: 10px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #4F96BA;
    width: 100%;
}

/*Media Queries*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

  #top-logo {
        display: block;
    max-width: 50%;
    margin: 3px auto;
}
  .collapse.in {   
    min-height: 150px;
    background-color:#4F96BA;
    verflow-y:visible;
}
    .sub-menu-head {
        color: #fff;
    }
    nav {
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    ul.main-nav > li > a:after {
        display: none;
    }
    ul.main-nav > li:first-child {
        border-radius: 0px;
    }
    ul.main-nav > li {
        display: block;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
    }
    ul.main-nav > li > a {
        font-weight: 600;
    }
    ul.main-nav > li ul.sub-menu-lists > li a {
        color: #4F96BA;
        ;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .sub-menu-head {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    ul.main-nav > li:hover {
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    ul.main-nav > li:hover > a {

        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: 600;
    }
    .sub-menu-block {
        padding: 0 30px;
    }
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a {
        color: #000;
    }
    #big {
        display: none;
    }

}
/*end query*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {

    #top-logo, #searchie {
        display: none;
    }


    ul.main-nav {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
    }
    .sub-menu-block {
        padding: 15px;
    }
    /* Sub Menu */

    ul.main-nav > li > div.sub-menu-block {
        visibility: hidden;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        position: absolute;
        margin-top: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        color: #333;
        left: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        z-index: 3;
        font-size: 16px;
        border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
        opacity: 0;
        /*CSS animation applied for sub menu : Slide from Top */

        -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
        -o-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
        transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);
        -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg);
        -ms-transform: rotateX(90deg);
        transform: rotateX(90deg);
        -webkit-transform-origin: top center;
        -ms-transform-origin: top center;
        transform-origin: top center;
    }
    ul.main-nav > li:hover > div.sub-menu-block {
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotateX(0deg);
        transform: rotateX(0deg);
    }
    ul.main-nav > li > div.sub-menu-block > * {
        -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
        -moz-transition-property: opacity;
        -o-transition-property: opacity;
        transition-property: opacity;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
        -moz-transition-duration: 0.4s;
        -o-transition-duration: 0.4s;
        transition-duration: 0.4s;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    ul.main-nav > li:hover > div.sub-menu-block > * {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    .sub-menu-head {
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    /* List Separator: Outer Border */

    header.dark ul.main-nav > li > a {
        border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
    }
    header.mega ul.main-nav > li > a {
        border-right: 1px solid #666;
    }
    /* List Separator: Inner Border */

    ul.main-nav > li > a:after {
        content: '';
        width: 1px;
        height: 62px;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    header.dark ul.main-nav > li > a:after {
        background-color: #777;
    }
    header.mega ul.main-nav > li > a:after {
        background-color: #999;
    }
    /* Drop Down/Up Arrow for Mega Menu */

    ul.main-nav > li > a.mega-menu > span {
        display: block;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    ul.main-nav > li > a.mega-menu > span:after {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-left: 5px solid transparent;
        border-right: 5px solid transparent;
        border-top: 5px solid #fff;
        content: '';
        background-color: transparent;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 10px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    ul.main-nav > li:hover > a.mega-menu span:after {
        border-left: 5px solid transparent;
        border-right: 5px solid transparent;
        border-top: 0px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 5px solid #666;
    }
    .banners-area {
        border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    }

    #little {
        display: none;
    }
}
/*end query*/
/**************Additions****************/
/* 5 Columns */

.col-xs-15,
.col-sm-15,
.col-md-15,
.col-lg-15 {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.col-xs-15 {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .col-sm-15 {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .col-md-15 {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .col-lg-15 {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    }
}
```

html:

```
<div id="big">
   <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top navbar-main affix-top" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="50" role="navigation" >
      <div class="dark">
         <ul class="main-nav">
            <li class="top-level-link">
               <a class="mega-menu"><span>SOFTWARE</span></a>
               <div class="sub-menu-block" id="five-block">
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-15 col-sm-6">
                        <h2 class="sub-menu-head">Microsoft Office</h2>
                        <ul class="sub-menu-lists">
                           <li class="hover_drop_down">
                              <a href="#">Microsoft Office 2016<span class="caret"></span></a>    
                              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                 <li><a href="#">Office 2016 Home & Business</a></li>
                              </ul>
                           </li>
                           <li><a href="#">Microsoft Office 365</a> </li>
                        </ul>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-15 col-sm-6">
                        <h2 class="sub-menu-head">Windows</h2>
                        <ul class="sub-menu-lists">
                           <li><a>Microsoft Windows 10 Pro</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-15 col-sm-6">
                        <h2 class="sub-menu-head">SQL Server</h2>
                        <ul class="sub-menu-lists">
                           <li><a>Microsoft SQL Server 2016<span class="caret"></span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-15 col-sm-6">
                        <h2 class="sub-menu-head">Windows Server</h2>
                        <ul class="sub-menu-lists">
                           <li><a>Windows Server 2003 R2<span class="caret"></span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-15  col-sm-6">
                        <h2 class="sub-menu-head">Remote Desktop Services</h2>
                        <ul class="sub-menu-lists">
                           <li><a>Remote Desktop Services 2016<span class="caret"></span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </li>
            <li class="top-level-link">
               <a class="mega-menu"><span>ELECTRONICS</span></a>
               <div class="sub-menu-block">
                  <div class="row ">
                     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6" >
                        <h2 class="sub-menu-head">Software Resources</h2>
                        <ul class="sub-menu-lists" >
                           <li><a>Software Resources</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6" >
                        <h2 class="sub-menu-head">Software Resources</h2>
                        <ul class="sub-menu-lists" >
                           <li><a>Software Resources</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6" >
                        <h2 class="sub-menu-head">Software Resources</h2>
                        <ul class="sub-menu-lists" >
                           <li><a>Software Resources</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6" >
                        <h2 class="sub-menu-head">Software Resources</h2>
                        <ul class="sub-menu-lists" >
                           <li><a>Software Resources</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<!--Desktop end-->
```

Comment: Not sure I understood what are you trying to accomplish. Do you want ".sub-menu-block" to be narrower (to get rid of the white spaces between the links), or you wish ".sub-menu-block" to stay full width and only make the links narrower?
In first case, remove widthh: 100% from ".sub-menu-block"
In the second case, remove width from "sub-menu-head" and "sub-menu-lists" and add "display: inline-block" for both. I hope this helped. If not, please add some more clarifications.

Comment: Ok so thank for the reply. I followed your advice  and it removed the white-space from the column 4 menu. As for the 5 column some of the menu items have really long names and I can't shorten them. I would rather have them stay on the same line with no wrap so those columns would need to adjust to that length, and in turn the menu around that.. Id like the mega menu to adjust to allow for the longest text.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just remove the width:100% from the div.sub-menu-block element to remove the extra white-space from the 4-column menu?

Comment: Yes that works, but how can I stop the word wrapping in the 5 column menu? those menu items need to fit on one line. How can i adjust the columns and mega menu to fit it appropriately?

Comment: What Kartick said. Add "white-space:nowrap;" to the menu item LIs.

Comment: it works but the the last column overflows past the menu border. How can I adjust the sub menu  block? If i set it too 100% width the over flow happens if I set a width like 1200px the menu is too large for the four column. I need a way to resize the menu depending on the longest line of text in a column.

Comment: Hrm. Something has to give. If the menu items cannot wrap, but they don't fit the spot them maybe make the font smaller?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

For keeping the names in 1 line take a look here
[CSS W3shcool attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp)

Comment: I tried that and ran into the column text overlapping the next column.